# add auto-scroll listview, android?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have listview in which elements are added on runtime that is click of a button.
This is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/form"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i select the edittext the keyboard appears and the elements get hidden behind the keyboard.  I want the contents of listview moveup when the keyboard appears so that i see the last elements in the list.

When i add a listelement on the onclick of the button the item gets add but i have to scroll down to see it.
I want it to immediately scroll to the last element when the element is added.

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

to your ListView, this should move the list up when keyboard pop up.

to scroll down to the last element try:

```
int n= //number of elements in the list;

yourList.setSelection(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tarek is right.  But increment your counter variable in each button setOnClickListener() and

declare your counter int variable outside the onClickListeners for example:

```
public class MyClass extends Fragment{

int arrayPosition = 0;//counter variable- set it to zero then increment in the buttons

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){...}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    final ArrayAdapter<YourClass> yourAdapter = new YourAdapter();
    final ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.imortant_list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);

    myButtonsetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ...whatever you button does here

                arrayPosition++;
                listView.setSelection(arrayPosition);

    }

    });
}
```